# ++i in while loop only change once

Tags: c, arrays, loops, while-loop, embedded

I'm working on an assignment for my Embedded C class and I have run into a problem which I can't seem to solve. My problem is that `++i` will only change once. The first time the loop runs `i` will be `0`, the second time `i` is `1` but after that `i` will always be `1` regardless of how many times the loop loops. Anyone have an idea of what the problem might be? I put in the `printf("%d\n", i);` just to see if `i` changed or not.

```
void addCar() {
    char choice = 'y';
    int i = 0;
    while((choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y') && i < MAX_CAR) {
        printf("Make: ");
        scanf("%s", fleet[i].make);

        getDate(1, i);

        getDate(2, i);

        printf("Purchaseprice: ");
        scanf("%lf", &fleet[i].purchasePrice);

        ++i;
        printf("%d\n", i);
        printf("Do you want to add another car? (Y/N)");
        scanf("%s", &choice);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You mustn't do `scanf("%s", &choice)`: there is not enough space in &choice "buffer" to hold the string you scan - **the scanned string is at least 2 characters long with the terminating '\0'**, and other variables in stack are overridden.

Use `scanf("%c", &choice)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But can this really cause ++i to not change every loop?

Comment: @MartinHjelm-Wallborg it absolutely can change other variables on the stack. Have you tried the code with the fix?

Comment: @MartinHjelm-Wallborg If the memory allocation is continuous, he next byte after `choice` is the first byte of `i`, so instead of writing `0` (the null-terminating character) in `choice[1]` it writes it in one of the byte of `i`.

Comment: @MartinHjelm-Wallborg Writing past the end of an array is undefined behavior, meaning that _anything_ can happen. _Anything_ includes other variables getting the wrong values, program counter jumping out to la-la-land, program crashes, or even that the program seems to work as expected.

Comment: @Evgeny yes I tried with scanf("%c", &choice) instead but once I did that I get thrown out of the loop straight away withouth even entering the Y/N...

Comment: Which would indicate that something else is writing in the choice "buffer"?!

Comment: @MartinHjelm-Wallborg: you're picking up a stray newline from the previous `scanf` call; the `%c` conversion specifier won't skip over leading whitespace where the `%s` and `%f` conversion specifiers do.  The fix is to add a blank space to the format string before the conversion specifier: `scanf(" %c", &choice);`